# How to find max from a composite set of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, composite

I have a table such as :

```
Year | Month
------------
2011    10   
2011    11   
2012    5   
2012    6
```

The query should return the latest "Month" for the latest "year".

Currently I'm doing something like

> Select MAX("Month") from table where "Year" in (select MAX("Year") from table)

But I'm not satisfied with query. Can someone suggest a more compact and cleaner way?

Comment: I think your query is clear enough apart from the in statement. I think the select MAX(Year) return a single value so you need an = sign instead of in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select top 1
    "Month"
from table
order by "Year" desc, "Month" desc
```

all right, for MySQL I think it should be

```
select
    "Month"
from table
order by "Year" desc, "Month" desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Yes, I'm more SQL Server person, I've edited post with suggestion for MySQL, I can not try it - have no MySQL access

Comment: Except for identifier quoting, which in MySQL should use backticks rather than double-quotes (which indicate a string literal), this looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select t1.months from
(select top 1 t.months as months,max(t.years) as years from
(select years,max(months) as months from cal group by years) t
group by t.months) t1
```